# Meteor Slingshot Cordova/Android "error : failed to upload file to cloud storage [-0]"

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-slingshot

I have a working meteor/cordova app that uses slingshot to upload to AWS/S3.  I am able to upload and view photos in-app from the browser and from iOS.

However, on Android I am unable to load photos from the AWS link provided by slingshot and stored in my database, and when I try to upload a photo I get an error that reads:

```
    "error : failed to upload file to cloud storage [-0]"
```

Is there anything android-specific that I have missed/that I should do to configure slingshot/my app in general for android?  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

relevant client-side code (minus file restriction):

```
//upload to AWS once file is selected
'change #imgUpload' : function(){
  var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("uploadFiles");
  var questionId = Session.get('selectedQuestion');
  uploader.send(document.getElementById('uploadInput').files[0], function (error, downloadUrl) {
    if (error) {
      // Log service detailed response
      console.log(error)
      console.error('Error uploading' );
      alert (error);
    }
    else {
      Meteor.call('uploadImage', questionId, downloadUrl);
    }
  });
```

relevant server-side method:

```
  'uploadImage' : function(questionId, downloadUrl){
check(questionId, String);
check(downloadUrl, String);
questionsList.update({_id: questionId},
                      {$set: {
                        picUrl: downloadUrl
                      }
                    });
}, //end upload image
```

Relevant server-side directive (minus file restriction):

```
Slingshot.createDirective("uploadFiles", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: <bucketname>,
  acl: "public-read",


  authorize: function(){
    //you can't upload if youre not logged in
    if(!this.userId){
      var message = "Please log in before posting files";
      throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
    }
    return true;
  },

  key: function(file){
    //store file in a directory based on a users team name
    var teamName = Meteor.user().roles.defaultGroup[0]
    return teamName + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

relevant mobile_config.js accessrules:

```
App.accessRule('https://<app-name>.herokuapp.com/*');
App.accessRule('http://<app-name>.herokuapp.com/*');
App.accessRule('https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/*');
App.accessRule('http://localhost:3010/*');
```

relevant template to display pic:

```
  {{#if theQuestion.picUrl}}
        <img src="{{theQuestion.picUrl}}" width="300px" height="300px"  class="userPic">
  {{/if}}
```

relevant template to upload pic:

```
<template name="uploader">
  <form id="imgUpload">
    <input id='uploadInput' class="fileLoader" name="file" type="file">
    <label for="file" class="uploadWords">Tap here to upload/take a  picture</label>
  </form>
```

file restriction:

```
    Slingshot.fileRestrictions("uploadFiles", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB (use null for unlimited)
});
```

Comment: Are you using the same file for each device?  What type of file is it?

Comment: I am, there are both jpegs and pngs, neither display, the uploads from android are jpegs

Comment: Can we see the file restriction code for the Slingshot server method?  Also, have you tried creating a Blob from the uploaded file and then sending the Blob to Slingshot? If this works on iOS and browser this seems silly, but worth a shot to see if anything changes.  Let me know if you need a quick code snippet for that. I am doing almost the same thing with Slingshot, but haven't used it on Android yet.

Comment: It's just the boilerplate restriction from the slingshot docs, I've added it to the question though.  I'll try uploading a blob next and let you know how it goes (this isnt my only project, so it might be a second), thanks for your help/input!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference if anyone else is having this problem, I ended up tearing out meteor slingshot and going with https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3 .  It worked well.

Feel free to message me for any code, but I essentially used the boilerplate code provided in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue and I what I found is this.
File object that we create using Webkit is different from the file Object that is available on Andriod.
File Object constructor on Webkit is

```
new File([Blob],"FileName.png",{type: "image/png"});
```

Where as on Cordova it is different, to resolve the issue when using 'uploader.send' instead of passing a file object (Which internally been created by Meteor/Cordova) pass Blob object directly, the code which I used to create the blob object is

```
b64toBlob = function(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
contentType = contentType || '';
sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data.split(',')[1]);
var byteArrays = [];

for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}

var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
return blob;}
```

And the way I passed finally constructed my code is

```
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    console.log("Detected Mobile device");
    var blobFile = b64toBlob(data, "image/png");
    blobFile.name = "userPhoto.png";
    newFile = blobFile;
} else {
    newFile = new File([b64toBlob(data, "image/png")], "usePhoto.png", {type: "image/png"});
}
uploader.send(newFile, function (error, downloadUrl) {
//Deal with the download URL
}
```

Comment: I think this might be because Cordova's File plugin (cordova-plugin-file) overwrites several native objects, including the standard File object. I reached the same solution by simply capturing the original File object before cordova-plugin-file initialized.